# Как скопировать таблицу из одной базы данных в другую в SQLite на Python

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Хочу создать бота замен занятий для студентов.
Есть сайт замен, где через специальную программу создаются замены, таблицы которые нужно копировать с сайта (базы данных): 1 (первая) таблица преподавателей, 2 (вторая) таблица групп, 3 (третья) таблица замен. 1 и 2 таблицы будут копироваться в том случаи когда том что-то добавится. 3 таблица должна обновляется (копироваться) каждый день.
Есть данные для входа IP адрес (порт), логин и пароль.

**Нужна функция как обновить (скопировать) 3 (третью) таблицу из базы данных сайта в базу данных бота с помощью SQLite3?**

Бот будет на python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть как реализовано это [здесь](https://gist.github.com/vgarvardt/3272957)

И в целом для решения вашей задачи нужно выполнить эти команды с помощью python

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;

INSERT INTO other.tbl
SELECT * FROM main.tbl;
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что подключится к базе сайта через SQLite. А можно подключится через mariadb к базе данных и скопировать таблице в базу SQLite? спасибо